# How to display Javascript methods in a 'group' in JSDOC?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there are possibility to 'group' functions within a class (AMD/RequireJS Module) ? My classes have sometimes over 20+ functions which actually belong to a specific 'interface implementation' and sometimes they just need to be grouped for better readability.

I checked the available jsDoc tags but none of them seem to provide this, in Doxygen there are number of tags...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

this is one way to do it, your module shape may very, but this works with classes and modules:

```
/**
* @module foobar
*
* @memberof module:foobar
* @param {string} arg an argument
**/
function one (arg) {
    console.log(arg)
}
module.exports = {
    one: one
}
```

the key is to use @memberof, [documented here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-memberof.html).

you can use it with @class documentation, or @module documentation, so it can work with any variety of ES5, ES6, or TypeScript Class or Module shapes, so long as you document the container object (class or module) with @class or @module.

result:
[image]

Comment: acceptable workaround for now, but waiting for real grouping feature in jsdoc ;)